# ORA-01422 Error Occurred When I Call Procedure with Number Parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad, plsql-developer, procedure-definition

I want to write PL/SQL Procedure that updates salary which is less than 2000. I wrote this procedure.And when i call it with integer id 'ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows' error is thrown by TOAD. My procedure is like below:

```
DECLARE
PROCEDURE update_salary(ID customers.id%type) is
   c_sal  customers.salary%type;
BEGIN
  SELECT salary 
  INTO c_sal 
  FROM customers 
  WHERE id = ID;
   dbms_output.put_line ('Before update operation salary is:' || c_sal);

  --dbms_output.put_line ('Parameter :' || ID);

   IF (c_sal <= 2000) THEN
      UPDATE customers 
      SET salary =  salary + 1000
      WHERE id = ID;
      dbms_output.put_line ('Salary updated');
   END IF;

  SELECT salary 
  INTO c_sal 
  FROM customers 
  WHERE id=ID;
   dbms_output.put_line ('After update operation salary is:' || c_sal);
END;

BEGIN
update_salary(1);
END;
/
```

I print parameter id with dbms_output. The parameter is coming correctly. How can i fix this error !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naming your parameter the same way you named your column is quite unfortunate.

```
  SELECT salary 
  INTO c_sal 
  FROM customers 
  WHERE id = ID;
```

In the above statement, typing `id` in lowercase or `ID` in uppercase makes no difference, it is case insensitive. Just because you named your PL/SQL parameter `ID` (in uppercase), does not mean the database will use it when you type `ID` (in uppercase) in the above. Even if the `id` in `customers` has unique values, the above `SELECT` returns all* rows from the table, because the `id` column precedes the `ID` parameter, and `id` always* equals `ID` (*except for `NULLs`).

You could just simply use a different name for your parameter, for example I usually use the `p_` prefix for them, so your `ID` parameter could be changed to `P_ID`:

```
DECLARE
PROCEDURE update_salary(P_ID customers.id%type) is
   c_sal  customers.salary%type;
BEGIN
  SELECT salary 
  INTO c_sal 
  FROM customers 
  WHERE id = P_ID;
   dbms_output.put_line ('Before update operation salary is:' || c_sal);

  --dbms_output.put_line ('Parameter :' || ID);

   SELECT  salary 
   INTO  c_sal
   FROM customers
   WHERE id = P_ID;
   IF (c_sal <= 2000) THEN
      UPDATE customers 
      SET salary =  salary + 1000
      WHERE id = P_ID;
      dbms_output.put_line ('Salary updated');
   END IF;

  SELECT salary 
  INTO c_sal 
  FROM customers 
  WHERE id=P_ID;
   dbms_output.put_line ('After update operation salary is:' || c_sal);
END;

BEGIN
update_salary(1);
END;
/
```

Answer (score -1):

This mean query:

```
SELECT salary 
  INTO c_sal
```

return more than 1 row
check the table for count records with ID = 1

if ID by any legal reason non unique - need make LOOP